# Getting google map API issues in Direction API

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-places-api, direction

I am getting this issues in google map direction API even this credential is working for places API

```
  {
 "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request 
received from IP address 103.87.59.60, with empty referer",
"routes" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the specific direction API key (that you can find [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/)). You can not use the same API key for direction API and places API.